# How to get the .dSYM file from expo EAS build?

Tags: react-native, build, expo, dsym, expo-build

I have successfully built an app using Expo EAS build and now I want to retrieve the .dSYM file generated.

Anyone know if it's possible? I couldn't find anything related to that in the Expo AES build docs.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to `eas.json`:

```
"ios": {
  "buildArtifactPaths": "ios/build/*"
}
```

https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/968#issuecomment-1172794557

Answer (score 1):

Your `eas.json` should look like this:

```
{
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "buildArtifactPaths": ["ios/build/*"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I took the minimal `eas.json` template from Expo documentation [here](https://docs.expo.dev/build/eas-json/) and added the `ios` configuration in the `production` profile. In this example, there are three profiles: `development`, `preview`, and `production`.

If you do not specify a profile when executing `eas build`, `production` is used by default. `eas build:configure` will error if you do not have a profile named `production`. If you wanted to move the ios configuration code to a different profile, you would have to execute `eas build --profile <yourProfileName> --platform ios`.

Execute `eas build:configure` and `eas build --platform ios`. When the build completes, go to https://expo.dev, click on the build, and click 'Download artifacts'.

This will download a file named "artifacts-yourExpoBuildId.tar". Opening this file will add a folder in the same directory named "ios". In "ios" > "build", you will find a file named "yourAppName.app.dSYM.zip". Open/unzip this file to obtain the .dSYM file for that build.

Answer (score 0):

### The new key is: "applicationArchivePath".

```
    {
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "applicationArchivePath": "ios/build/*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```