# How can I resolve iOS publish crashing on opening?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo, crash-reports

## Managed Expo React-Native Workflow Issues

### App crashes immediately only on iOS and only when published to TestFlight

Hello, I'm still getting acquainted with the new codebase and this whole expo/react-native codebase and workflow, and I'm running into something very strange. When I build this app locally (for iOS or Android, it works great. I can publish to the App Store on android and it works great. When I publish to TestFlight (via `was submit --platform iOS` OR via Xcode Archive > publish flow) the app crashes before the splash screen has time to open up.

We're currently operating in Expo SDK 46 and react native 0.69.9. We will be updating versions once we manage to get this to work, as I believe it's something with our code, and updating versions on top of it only broadens what could be causing various errors. ANYWAY. Here are my various config files (keep in mind, the same codebase is being used for the web, iOS, and Android apps, and has worked great until recently)

I've been trying for weeks, and searching far and wide for answers. It has lead me to realize that there were other dependencies that weren't being implemented correctly, but I've went through and fixed all of them, and I'm just in the final stretch, and would REALLY appreciate any help or guidance possible.

Let me know if there's anything else that I can do to provide more information, or tips on how to finish symbolicating the last couple lines in the crash report... Anything and everything is appreciated.

```
Expo: 46.0.0
React-Native: 0.69.9
XCode: 14.3
```

### Package.json

```
{
  //Generic app related stuff
  },
  "scripts": {
    //Scripts with company app name in it...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9",
    "@expo/ngrok": "^4.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.17.1",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.2.2",
    "@progress/kendo-react-charts": "^5.9.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-intl": "^5.9.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^5.10.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "~15.4.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.8",
    "@react-navigation/core": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.1",
    "calendar-link": "^2.2.0",
    "check-password-strength": "^2.0.7",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "expo": "~46.0.21",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.3.0",
    "expo-calendar": "~10.3.0",
    "expo-clipboard": "~3.1.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.2.4",
    "expo-dev-client": "~1.3.1",
    "expo-firebase-analytics": "~7.2.0",
    "expo-firebase-core": "~5.2.0",
    "expo-linking": "~3.2.4",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "firebase": "^9.6.5",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0",
    "immutable-js": "^0.3.1-6",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-content-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-gtm-module": "^2.0.11",
    "react-multi-date-picker": "^3.3.4",
    "react-native": "0.69.9",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-modal-selector": "^2.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-version-check-expo": "^3.4.7",
    "react-native-web": "^0.18.9",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "react-switch": "^7.0.0",
    "react-time-picker": "^5.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.0",
    "util": "^0.12.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "5.4.2",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^12.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^27.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.5.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.0.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.68.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

### eas.json

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.10.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },

    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "image": "macos-monterey-12.6-xcode-14.2"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "appleId": "...",
        "ascAppId": "1609264690",
        "appleTeamId": "VT93GRP65C"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### app.config.js

```js
export default ({ config }) => {
  return {
    ...config,
    extra: {
      environment: process.env.ENVIRONMENT,
      eas: {
        projectId: "...",
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          android: {
            minSdkVersion: 30,
            compileSdkVersion: 31,
            targetSdkVersion: 31,
            buildToolsVersion: "31.0.0",
          },
          ios: {
            deploymentTarget: "16.1",
            useFrameworks: "static",
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```

### `/ios/Podfile`

```
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/package.json')"`), "native_modules")

require 'json'
podfile_properties = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'Podfile.properties.json'))) rescue {}

platform :ios, podfile_properties['ios.deploymentTarget'] || '12.4'
install! 'cocoapods',
  :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'MyModuleName' do
  use_expo_modules!
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_frameworks! :linkage => podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks'].to_sym if podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks']

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => true,
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Dir.pwd}/.."
  )

  # Uncomment to opt-in to using Flipper
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work
  #
  # if !ENV['CI']
  #   use_flipper!()
  # end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)

    # This is necessary for Xcode 14, because it signs resource bundles by default
    # when building for devices.
    installer.target_installation_results.pod_target_installation_results
      .each do |pod_name, target_installation_result|
      target_installation_result.resource_bundle_targets.each do |resource_bundle_target|
        resource_bundle_target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end
  end

  post_integrate do |installer|
    begin
      expo_patch_react_imports!(installer)
    rescue => e
      Pod::UI.warn e
    end
  end
end
```

### Crash Report

#### It's mostly symbolicated, really trying to figure out how to fill in the rest

```
Incident Identifier: DFC14832-52FC-454A-960D-E6A0AB39D29F
Beta Identifier:     1C716AB4-A881-415A-9672-25A4A5BAC935
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,8
Process:             MyApp [26958]
Version:             5.0.22 (283)
AppStoreTools:       14E221
AppVariant:          1:iPhone11,8:16
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.myriadmobile.Company-My-App [449]

Date/Time:           2023-05-30 17:27:32.3550 -0500
Launch Time:         2023-05-30 17:27:31.8972 -0500
OS Version:          iPhone OS 16.5 (20F66)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    5.02.02
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  1

Application Specific Information:
abort() called


Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                         0x19b670cb4 __exceptionPreprocess + 164
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1947183d0 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   MyApp                          0x10040efc4 0x1001b4000 + 2469828
3   MyApp                          0x1001c8470 0x1001b4000 + 83056
4   MyApp                          0x1001c8cb4 0x1001b4000 + 85172
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19b6d9c04 __invoking___ + 148
6   CoreFoundation                         0x19b687cb4 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 428
7   CoreFoundation                         0x19b6876cc -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 64
8   MyApp                          0x10043cccc 0x1001b4000 + 2657484
9   MyApp                          0x10043ee44 0x1001b4000 + 2666052
10  MyApp                          0x10043eacc 0x1001b4000 + 2665164
11  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a2b35320 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
12  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a2b36eac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
13  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a2b3e534 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 668
14  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a2b3f0a4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 384
15  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a2b49cdc _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb414ddc _pthread_wqthread + 288
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb414b7c start_wqthread + 8

Kernel Triage:
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage


Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1da5d3c84 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1da5e6b54 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1da5e6e2c mach_msg_overwrite + 540
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1da5d41c8 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19b6e0024 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19b6e1250 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x19b6e63ec CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   GraphicsServices                       0x1d6bab35c GSEventRunModal + 164
8   UIKitCore                              0x19da736e8 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
9   UIKitCore                              0x19da7334c UIApplicationMain + 340
10  MyApp                          0x1001b99d8 0x1001b4000 + 23000
11  dyld                                   0x1babe6dec start + 2220

Thread 1 name:   Dispatch queue: com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue
Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1da5da558 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb41b118 pthread_kill + 268
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x1a2b97178 abort + 180
3   libc++abi.dylib                        0x1fb359bf8 abort_message + 132
4   libc++abi.dylib                        0x1fb349444 demangling_terminate_handler() + 348
5   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x19471dea4 _objc_terminate() + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                        0x1fb358fbc std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                        0x1fb358f60 std::terminate() + 56
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a2b36ec0 _dispatch_client_callout + 40
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a2b3e534 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 668
10  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a2b3f0a4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 384
11  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a2b49cdc _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb414ddc _pthread_wqthread + 288
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb414b7c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb414b74 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb414b74 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb414b74 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb414b74 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb414b74 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1da5d3c84 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1da5e6b54 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1da5e6e2c mach_msg_overwrite + 540
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1da5d41c8 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19b6e0024 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19b6e1250 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x19b6e63ec CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   Foundation                             0x19596efd4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212
8   Foundation                             0x19596eebc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 64
9   UIKitCore                              0x19dba63fc -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 416
10  Foundation                             0x195988544 __NSThread__start__ + 716
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb4156b8 _pthread_start + 148
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb414b88 thread_start + 8

Thread 8 name:  com.facebook.react.JavaScript
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1da5d3c84 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1da5e6b54 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1da5e6e2c mach_msg_overwrite + 540
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1da5d41c8 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19b6e0024 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19b6e1250 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x19b6e63ec CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   MyApp                          0x100420938 0x1001b4000 + 2541880
8   Foundation                             0x195988544 __NSThread__start__ + 716
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb4156b8 _pthread_start + 148
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb414b88 thread_start + 8

Thread 9 name:  hades
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1da5d4558 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb41c078 _pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2   libc++.1.dylib                         0x1a9cb3ef8 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28
3   hermes                                 0x1010b998c 0x100fa8000 + 1120652
4   hermes                                 0x1010b9740 0x100fa8000 + 1120064
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb4156b8 _pthread_start + 148
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb414b88 thread_start + 8

Thread 10 name:  hermes-chrome-inspector-conn
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1da5d4558 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb41c078 _pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2   libc++.1.dylib                         0x1a9cb3ef8 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28
3   MyApp                          0x10052ccc4 0x1001b4000 + 3640516
4   MyApp                          0x1004e6798 0x1001b4000 + 3352472
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb4156b8 _pthread_start + 148
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb414b88 thread_start + 8

Thread 11 name:  hermes-inspector
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1da5d4558 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb41c078 _pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2   libc++.1.dylib                         0x1a9cb3ef8 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28
3   MyApp                          0x10052ccc4 0x1001b4000 + 3640516
4   MyApp                          0x1004e6798 0x1001b4000 + 3352472
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb4156b8 _pthread_start + 148
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb414b88 thread_start + 8

Thread 12 name:  hades
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1da5d4558 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb41c078 _pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2   libc++.1.dylib                         0x1a9cb3ef8 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28
3   hermes                                 0x1010b998c 0x100fa8000 + 1120652
4   hermes                                 0x1010b9740 0x100fa8000 + 1120064
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb4156b8 _pthread_start + 148
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb414b88 thread_start + 8

Thread 13 name:  hermes-chrome-inspector-conn
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1da5d4558 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb41c078 _pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2   libc++.1.dylib                         0x1a9cb3ef8 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28
3   MyApp                          0x10052ccc4 0x1001b4000 + 3640516
4   MyApp                          0x1004e6798 0x1001b4000 + 3352472
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb4156b8 _pthread_start + 148
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb414b88 thread_start + 8

Thread 14 name:  hermes-inspector
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1da5d4558 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb41c078 _pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2   libc++.1.dylib                         0x1a9cb3ef8 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28
3   MyApp                          0x10052ccc4 0x1001b4000 + 3640516
4   MyApp                          0x1004e6798 0x1001b4000 + 3352472
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb4156b8 _pthread_start + 148
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb414b88 thread_start + 8

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb414b74 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1fb414b74 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 1 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x00000001fb35d647   x5: 0x000000016fcd2850   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000800
    x8: 0x3031646439b013ef   x9: 0x30316465567d23ef  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x000000000000000b
   x12: 0x000000000000000b  x13: 0x00000000001ff800  x14: 0x00000000000007fb  x15: 0x0000000091e3b006
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x000000016fcd3000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000d03  x21: 0x000000016fcd30e0  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x000000016fcd30e0
   x24: 0x0000000280194d68  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000114  x27: 0x000000028358d480
   x28: 0x000000028358d480   fp: 0x000000016fcd27c0   lr: 0x00000001fb41b118
    sp: 0x000000016fcd27a0   pc: 0x00000001da5da558 cpsr: 0x40000000
   far: 0x00000001eef4b6d8  esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

Binary Images:
       0x1001b4000 -        0x100673fff MyApp arm64  <a256e3698b863723ada06ddf764d4dab> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4AA8756D-AF9C-45C9-AF7B-269311C60F20/MyApp.app/MyApp
       0x100fa8000 -        0x10123ffff hermes arm64  <ebc813373fec3086bc733de7e9493e43> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4AA8756D-AF9C-45C9-AF7B-269311C60F20/MyApp.app/Frameworks/hermes.framework/hermes
       0x100a60000 -        0x100a6bfff libobjc-trampolines.dylib arm64e  <695a8449aae838b6851cced0b1176f03> /private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
       0x1da5d3000 -        0x1da60aff7 libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <2f78311097393f18a2345fb92512529d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x19b667000 -        0x19ba4efff CoreFoundation arm64e  <4230c12242e8383bbeecee7b61f8bb61> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
       0x1d6baa000 -        0x1d6bb2fff GraphicsServices arm64e  <e830ad84d6123b6b8de7ea61a786d132> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
       0x19d6d6000 -        0x19eefafff UIKitCore arm64e  <b3834960244b34e49ea0ca4bb44ef0f3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
       0x1babd1000 -        0x1bac56a23 dyld arm64e  <8a423f3fb318315e99c705ee532e9c0d> /usr/lib/dyld
       0x1fb414000 -        0x1fb41fff3 libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  <8894310a745f340799f01fd54442561d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
       0x1a2b7a000 -        0x1a2bf7ff3 libsystem_c.dylib arm64e  <3548f8ee7a073b678d699c7d42096513> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
       0x1fb348000 -        0x1fb35ffff libc++abi.dylib arm64e  <b65049d9dda43d039e130b4795138702> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
       0x194700000 -        0x194743f9f libobjc.A.dylib arm64e  <085a190c621438eaaccb428c3e8afa65> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
       0x1a2b33000 -        0x1a2b79fff libdispatch.dylib arm64e  <bb347f0ef21c360782e6c8d750fdbf8c> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
       0x19592d000 -        0x19620afff Foundation arm64e  <6e76dc9611af3b2eb71e215f9cc6e822> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
       0x1a9ca1000 -        0x1a9d2dff7 libc++.1.dylib arm64e  <ffa7a30db5203cda8a7f63c6cd922df9> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib

EOF
```

## Things that I've Tried:

- `react-native doctor`
- `npx expo-doctor`
- Updating the `react-native-reanimated` version along with the `react-native-gesture-handler`
- Fixed the implementation of our firebase analytics
- Removing `expo-updates`
- modifying the `Podfiles` with various things that solved other people's very similar issues
- Just about everything I could find on the internet related to any of the error messages I've whittled down from to get here.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and specifying `"react-native-reanimated": "3.5.4"` in my `package.json` solved it for me. I see that you already tried updating the version, so if that still doesn't work, you can symbolicate the crash report for more clues about the crash.

If you see lines such as `<yourAppName> 0x10040efc4 0x1001b4000 + 2469828`, your crash report is not fully symbolicated. The only method to symbolicate the crash report that worked for me is to use a publicly available script.

1. `git clone https://github.com/tomieq/AppleCrashScripts`
2. `cd AppleCrashScripts`
3. Follow instructions in the README. You may need to convert your crash `.txt` into a `.ips` by renaming the file extension.
4. If you don't have a `.dSYM` file for your build, which may be the case if you just built with EAS, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77291322/22737945). If the script can't find a `.dSYM` file, try moving the `.dSYM` into the `AppleCrashScripts` directory. You must symbolicate the crash report using the `.dSYM` file associated with the build that crashed.
5. Now you should see error messages that point you in the right direction. A fully symbolicated line should not have any hexadecimal numbers, such as 0x10043cccc, next to `<yourAppName>`.

As you are developing in Expo Go, a rule of thumb is that if executing `npx expo start --no-dev --minify` crashes the app, the app will crash in TestFlight.